# USB drive not getting recognized as scsi device in custom linux kernel

Tags: linux, usb-flash-drive, kernel, linux-kernel, scsi

I am facing a slow write speed problem with a USB drive in my custom linux kernel. I suspected to be a hardware problem but with the same hardware and Opensuse 12.1 OS, write speed of my USB drive is much faster.

I also observed that there is a significant difference in dmesg output when my USB pen drive is plugged in OpenSuse 12.1 and in my custom kernel.

**dmesg in OpenSuse12.1**

```
[  665.417077] usb 2-2: USB disconnect, device number 4
[  668.676014] usb 2-2: new high speed USB device number 5 using ehci_hcd
[  668.812675] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0815, idProduct=2002
[  668.812679] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  668.812682] usb 2-2: Product: USBInstallMedia
[  668.812685] usb 2-2: Manufacturer:         
[  668.812687] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 070B49D39981F580
[  668.813052] scsi7 : usb-storage 2-2:1.0
[  669.813701] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access              USBDrive  PMAP PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  669.813893] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  670.912190] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] 62554112 512-byte logical blocks: (32.0 GB/29.8 GiB)
[  670.913182] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[  670.913186] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
[  670.914181] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page present
[  670.914185] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  670.918180] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page present
[  670.918184] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  670.919112]  sdc: sdc1
[  670.923056] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page present
[  670.923060] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  670.923063] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

**dmesg in my Custom kernel:**

```
usb 2-1: new high speed USB device number 3 using ehci_hcd
usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0815, idProduct=2002
usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
usb 2-1: Product: USBDrive
usb 2-1: Manufacturer:         
usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 070B49D39981F580
 ubb: ubb1
```

From the dmesg output it looks like my USB device is recognized as scsi device in OpenSuse 12.1 and in my custom kernel it is not recognized as scsi device.

I suspect this could be a possible reason for slow write speed in my custom kernel.. correct me if I am wrong..

And if I want my USB device to be recognized as scsi device do I need to enable any Kernel configuration ? If yes, it would be helpful if anyone can point me what are the kernel configurations should I modify. Thanks.

Comment: Did you enable SCSI in your custom kernel? Check the kernel configuration. There are *loads* of options which can influence the presence of the driver.

Comment: Thanks.. the problem was, USB drive was using a low performance driver called **UB** driver.. Disabling the configuration item  `CONFIG_BLK_DEV_UB` in kernel makes my USB drives to be identified as scsi devices...